# Are jewish rabbis NOT disqualified from inheritance?

Tags: crusader-kings-2

I'm playing CK2 2.0.4. I know it's old version, but I strongly dislike all this India stuff. During my Khazar campaign, I tried to disqualify my second son from gavelkind inheritance by giving him temple and making a rabbi. This was to no avail - he is still listed as a heir.

I fully expected to find something on the topic, but internet seems quiet about this. Is such behaviour confirmed or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: How much in-game time has passed? I don't recall the exact amount of time it takes, but IIRC the game only recalculates succession every so often. You can also force it by typing "recalc_succ" into the console.

Comment: I promptly reloaded the game, but I will try your solution too.

Comment: Didn't work. The rabbi is still in the line of inheritance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being a temple-holder only disqualifies from succession if your religion is in the Christian religion group.

I think this is because Christian temple-holders are prohibited from marriage, whereas other religions allow their temple holders to get married freely (for all religions I have played at least). Being prohibited from marriage means they should (if they are good Christians) have no children, and thus they are a dead-end for inheritance.